# CMake: library dependency satisfied by different variants

Tags: cmake

In our project, we have a library A which depends on library B which depends on library C1. However, for testing purposes, we want to replace library C1 by some library of fakes, C2.

Working CMakeLists.txt:

```
# works, but not CMake-style
add_library(libC1 c1.cpp)
add_library(libC2 c2.cpp)
add_library(libB b.cpp)
add_library(libA a.cpp)
add_executable(e1 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e1 libA libB libC1)
add_executable(e2 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e2 libA libB libC2)
```

Code:

```
// a.cpp
void b();
void a() { b(); }

// b.cpp
void c();
void b() { c(); }

// c1.cpp
#include <iostream>
void c() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }

// c2.cpp
#include <iostream>
void c() { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }

// e.cpp
void a();
int main() { a(); }
```

Now, it would be nice not to have explicit mentions of libB everywhere we use libA, like:

```
# doesn't work
add_library(libC1 c1.cpp)
add_library(libC2 c2.cpp)
add_library(libB b.cpp)
add_library(libA a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libA libB)
add_executable(e1 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e1 libA libC1)
add_executable(e2 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e2 libA libC2)
```

However, this doesn't work since now the libraries are passed in the order libA libCx libB to the linker, causing "undefined reference" errors. **Is there a nice way of solving this?**

One way I am aware of is keeping two variants of each library, like

```
# works, but clumsy
add_library(libC1 c1.cpp)
add_library(libC2 c2.cpp)
add_library(libB b.cpp)
add_library(libB1 dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libB1 libB libC1)
add_library(libB2 dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libB2 libB libC2)
add_library(libA a.cpp)
add_library(libA1 dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libA1 libA libB1)
add_library(libA2 dummy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libA2 libA libB2)
add_executable(e1 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e1 libA1)
add_executable(e2 e.cpp)
target_link_libraries(e2 libA2)
```

This is either overly intrusive (if done locally at each library definition) or requires a full copy of the dependency hierarchy somewhere else (if done where the library of fakes is defined).

Comment: `are passed in the order` cmake should pass each library _twice_ so that no such errors should happen and so that order does not matter. Can't you just `if(use_fake) add_library(libC1 c1.cpp) else() add_library(libC1 c2.cpp) endif()`? `add_library(libB1 dummy.cpp)` there is `add_library(libB1 INTERFACE)` which I think would pass better here.

Comment: Unless you have cyclic dependencies, passing the libraries twice (or using linker groups) should not be necessary. `if(use_fake)` I want both targets present in my build system, so I can do different kinds of tests without switching the build.

Comment: `Unless you have cyclic dependencies, passing the libraries twice (or using linker groups) should not be necessary` - no, passing libraries twice is _never_ necessary. Cmake already duplicates each library. For reference [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#cyclic-dependencies-of-static-libraries) `When another target links to one of the libraries, CMake repeats the entire connected component`. The option that you present that "doesn't work" - it should work. Also, make `e.cpp` an OBJECT library so that it isn't compiled twice.

Comment: failing example produces (with Ubuntu 19.10)
`: && /usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/e1.dir/e.cpp.o  -o e1  liblibA.a liblibC1.a liblibB.a && :
/usr/bin/ld: liblibB.a(b.cpp.o): in function \`b()':
b.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to \`c()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.` Using make instead on ninja gives similar output.